# siemens star with scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm trying to draw [siemens star](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aSiemens_star.svg&page=1)  with Scilab and I can't get it done.

Any idea why the following code doesn't work?

```
t = 0:.001:2*%pi;
xc = 4;
yc= 4;
r =2 ;
n = 1:length(t)/32 : length(t);
v =0:.001:r;
for k =1:length(n)
    if modulo(k,2) ==0 then
           for a=1:length(t)
           for b =1:length(v)
               x(a) = xc+ (r-v(b)) *cos(t(a));
                y(a) = yc+ (r-v(b))* sin(t(a));
               set(gca(),"auto_clear","off")  
               plot(x,y,"black");
           end;
       end;
   else 
     x=xc;
     y=yc;
 end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What "doesn't work"?

Comment: It just don't run, I get an empty figure

Comment: What happens if you stop the program a few times in the middle and run plot(x,y,"black");

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thanks for your suggestion but I made it with help of other functions "xfarc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks xenoclast for you suggestion but here is my code, I think a it's pretty short :

```
plot2d(0,0,-1,"030"," ",[-2,-2,2,2]);
n=16 // number of bands 
for i=1:n
   xfarc(-1.5,1.5,3,3,2*i*(180/n)*64,64*(180/n));
end
```

Comment: Yeah xfarc is certainly a more efficient way of doing it. I'd been seeing the question for a while and nobody had answered so I thought I'd see what was going on : )

Answer (score 1):

I know you've solved this a different way but it's worth noting that the `plot` call is hideously expensive and you're attempting to call it 4e8 times inside those three levels of nested loop.

If you reduce the sizes of the loops it works fine. Still takes an awful long time, and yes drawing solid blocks is more efficient that a series of lines : )